# Updating eigenvectors for small perturbation of source matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I have eigenvectors for matrix `A`, and I'm interested in eigenvectors of `A+eps`, where eps is a matrix of small norm. Is there an efficient procedure for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as eigenvalue perturbation problem.

For the special case of symmetric positive definite matrices $A$ and  $\epsilon$ with  distinct eigenvalues,  an approximation is as follows:

Let $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ be eigenvectors of $A$ such that $u_i^TAu_j = \delta_{ij}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots \lambda_n$.

That is $$Au_i = \lambda_i u_i$$

The new set of eigenvectors, $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ can be expressed as

$$v_i=u_i + \sum_{j=1\\ j\neq i}^{n} \frac{u_j^T\epsilon u_i}{\lambda_i - \lambda_j}u_j$$

Wikipedia references: [eigenvalue perturbation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_perturbation)

Remark: I notice that the wikipedia page does not address what happens when $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$.

Comment: Hm, does this work only for infinitesimal eps? I was expecting this would need some iterative procedure, which takes longer for larger eps

Comment: Yes, we need $\epsilon$ to be small since we are dropping higher order terms. I wonder if power method will work if you use $u$ as starting point of the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, power method seems like ideal solution for the top eigenvector. Since we are starting close to the solution it will only need couple of iterations. Not sure if this helps for the remaining eigenvectors though

Comment: Ah, thanks for the feedback. I wonder if the following works: After obtaining the first component, you can try to subtract the first component from the matrix and apply the previous trick to  the second largest eigen-pair?